# MATLAB : display 3 or more spectrograms side by side

Tags: matlab, plot, audio-processing, spectrogram

For the sake of visualisation, i need to randomly display from 3 to 6 spectrograms in Matlab. I have an array of 800 vectorized wav files, i am randomly picking 3 of them, and want them to pop up in a figure showing the spectrograms of each side-by-side:

```
 load('training_set.mat');
    m = size(X, 1);
    % Randomly select 3 wavs
    rand_indices = randperm(m);
    sel = X(rand_indices(1:3), :);
```

I am very new to Matlab and i did try to write a for loop which takes each sample out of "sel" and generates a spectogram for it, but i didn't achieve any result. ( i use the specgram function).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `subplot` command to display multiple plots side by side in one `figure` window:

```
figure
subplot(131)  % 1st number is # rows 
              % 2nd number is # columns
              % 3rd number is plot index
plot(x1,y1)
subplot(132)
plot(x2,y2)
subplot(133)
plot(x3,y3)
```

For your case you might try

```
figure
subplot(131)
plot(sel(1,:))
subplot(132)
plot(sel(2,:))
subplot(133)
plot(sel(3,:))
```